# simplify radicals and fractional exponents?

Tags: radicals

> This is the equation, please help me. I don't have any idea what to do with this. Thank you.
>
> √((32)^((4)/(5))(2^(n+1))^(4))/8^3 (16)^(n-1)
>
> That is a whole fraction within a radical sign all over √6:(9)

$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{32^{\frac45}(2^{(n+1)})^4}{8^316^{(n-1)}}}}{\sqrt[6] 9}$$

Comment: Did you mean this : $$\sqrt{((32)^{\frac45}(2^{n+1})^4)/8^3 (16)^{n-1} }$$?

Comment: I have put a version of your radical underneath what you wrote in the hope of clarifying what you are trying to compute. Could you please let me know in a comment whether this is correct, or what is wrong with it.

Comment: Is your expression $\sqrt{\dfrac{32^{4/5}\cdot(2^{n+1})^4}{8^3 \cdot 16^{n-1}}}$ divided by $\sqrt{\dfrac69}$?

Comment: put down the other equation, put it like a denominator and after which, make sixth root of 9 as a denominator again

Comment: alraxite, it is a sixthe root of 9 and without the radical sign

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - thanks for the comment. Note - what I have put needs an (n-1) as the power of 16 - but since there are competing edits and it is taking time for things to load on my computer I'll leave that to be changed in due course.

Comment: So your expression is $\sqrt{\dfrac{32^{4/5}\cdot(2^{n+1})^4}{8^3 \cdot 16^{n-1}}}$ divided by$\sqrt[9]6$?

Comment: @Alraxite its a sixth root of 9. and

Comment: So this: $\sqrt{\dfrac{32^{4/5}\cdot(2^{n+1})^4}{8^3 \cdot 16^{n-1}}}/(\sqrt[6]{9})$?

Comment: @Alraxite yes, :)

Comment: @ikaidubidu I've adjusted again - is it now correct?

Comment: @MarkBennet and divide it by sixth root of 9 :)

Comment: that's it @MarkBennet :)

Comment: oh wait, the 16 should have the parenthesis, not the exponent :) @MarkBennet

Comment: @ikaidubidu I think the parentheses here are not wholly necessary except for clarifying the order of operations. But the way the expression is now written would do that without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

First let's simplify the numerator:

$\sqrt{\dfrac{32^{4/5}\cdot(2^{n+1})^4}{8^3 \cdot 16^{n-1}}}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{(2^5)^{4/5}\cdot(2^{n+1})^4}{(2^3)^3 \cdot (2^4)^{n-1}}}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{2^4\cdot 2^{4n+4}}{2^9 \cdot 2^{4n-4}}}
=\sqrt{2^{4-9+(4n+4)-(4n-4)}}=\sqrt{2^3}=2^{\frac32}$.

The denominator:

$\sqrt[6]9=9^{\frac16}=(3^2)^{\frac16}=3^{\frac13}$.

So, your expression is
$\dfrac{2^\frac32}{3^\frac13}$.
You can rewrite this as $\dfrac{2^\frac96}{3^\frac26}=\sqrt[6]{\dfrac{2^9}{3^2}}=\sqrt[6]{\dfrac{512}{9}}$.

Comment: wait, on the numerator u had it 3/2 then u wrote 2/3 on the final expression?

Comment: @ikaidubidu Oh, you are correct!

Comment: is it a 3/2 or a 2/3?

Comment: @ikaidubidu I've edited my answer. It's a $\frac32$.

Comment: can i ask how did you come up with an exponent of 3 on the 4-9...etc etc ?

Comment: @ikaidubidu The expression $4-9+(4n+4)-(4n-4)$ simplifies to $3$. Because $4-9+(4n+4)-(4n-4)= -5 + 4n + 4 -4n +4=-5+8=3$.

Comment: thank you @Alraxite, now im able to discuss it tomorrow :)